# startx error doesn't load from terminal

Tags: xorg, gnome, freebsd

I have installed GNOME v2 in my freebsd but when I try to do `startx` it gives the following error.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Did you follow the instruction from http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/x11-wm.html ?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion offered in the screenshot?  Try running `startx -- :1` to start an instance of X on another display.

Comment: Yes I followed the official instructions, still it gave this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo service gdm start
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing xorg-minimal as follows

```
cd /usr/ports/x11/xorg-minimal
make install clean
```

and I was able to login via GNOME after a restart. Thanks everyone for your help.